# Adding constraints to an SQL Table with altering

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I have a defined type:

```
CREATE TYPE salary AS (salary numeric);
```

and a table holding data:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
lastname text,
firstname text,
salary salary, 
);
```

I want to use `ALTER TABLE`to add a constraint to the salary attribute:

```
ALTER TABLE employees ADD CONSTRAINT minimum_salary CHECK(salary > 1.47333);
```

this gives me the error `ERROR:  operator does not exist: salary > numeric`. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

To start with: a type seems overkill to just store a scalar value. Why no just create a check constraint on the column?

```
create table employees (
    lastname text, 
    firstname text, 
    salary numeric check(salary > 1.473333)
);
```

---

Coming back to your original question: I don't think that it is possible to put a check constraint on a type column. One thing you could do, however, is to [create a `domain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createdomain.html). Domains extend the standard types and do accept check constraints.

Consider [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3e851a84eb097079a54d1873ed0ca2b0):

```
create domain salary numeric check(value > 1.47333);
create table employees (lastname text, firstname text, salary salary);
insert into employees values('foo', 'bar', 1);
-- ERROR:  value for domain salary violates check constraint "salary_check"
```